# Can't find runtime error 13 cause

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set up a simple counter with double-criteria and I am stopped by

> runtime error 13

As you see bellow, I have multiple counters, all as Integer and I want them to count every hit there is lockated depending on the values of the columns D and A. )In case it matters: the Text in column D is being generated via Dates-comparisson in two other columns, but is formatted as text).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim lr, i, k, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s As Integer

a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = j = l = m = n = o = p = q = r = 0

Worksheets("overdue").Activate

lr = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

k = 1

For i = 1 To lr

If Cells(i, "D").Value = "OVERDUE" And Cells(i, "A") Like "*φίλτρου*" Then
a = a + 1
ElseIf Cells(i, "D").Value = "OVERDUE" And Cells(i, "A") Like "*Λιπαντικού*" Then
b = b + 1

k = k + 1

End If
Next i
```

I even tried to relocate the Worksheet-name right at the cell-syntax like

```
If Worksheets("overdue").Cells(i, "D").Value = "OVERDUE" And Worksheets("overdue").Cells(i, "A") Like "*ößëôñïõ*" Then
```

but it does not seem to help. Does anybody have a suggestion ?
I forgot to add, that the Debugger shows the line where the If is beggining, so the statement for the first counter.

Also, I see, that if I change the code radically and simplify it as much as possible, like this

```
 Sub testcounter()

 Dim cell As Range
 Dim a As Integer

 For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D1:D3500")

 If cell.Value = "1" Then
 a = a + 1
 End If
 Next

 MsgBox a

 End Sub
```

It still gives out the

> error 13

on the first line of the IF-statement.

Comment: "I have multiple counters, all as Integer" - only the last one is integer.  All the others are Variant.  In VBA you need to specify the type for each one: you cannot use a comma-separated list like that.  And that chained assignment doesn't work like you think.

Comment: OK, but even when I change the declaration to Dim lr As Integer, i As Integer, k As Integer etc. I get the same error

Comment: Integers aren't really used in VBA. They refer to 16 bit integers for compatibility with 16 bit office. The 32bit(and 64bit) integer is 32 bit and called a long in VBA. Integer +/- 32K v's a long +/- 2 billion.

Comment: Do your cells contain errors?

Comment: After looking closely I found out that from the 2785 entries, one was invalid and messed the whole thing up. I fixed it and it is running now. How can I bypass this type of inputs ?

Comment: By using `IsError`?

Answer (score 4):

1. All variables, except `s`, are not `Integer`s.
2. All variables (were they `Integer`s) are automatically initialized to zero.
3. `a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = j = l = m = n = o = p = q = r = 0` brings up *logical comparison*, i.e. it's checked whether r equals 0, then the result of this comparison is compared to `q` and so on.

Comment: ... and ultimately, only `a` is written to with the result of the logical comparison, all the other mentioned variables retain the values they had before the clause executed.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim a, b, c, d As Integer '<< only d is integer...

a = b = c = d = 0

Debug.Print "a", a
Debug.Print "b", b
Debug.Print "c", c
Debug.Print "d", d
```

Output:

```
a             True
b             
c             
d              0
```